# How can I apply a background to a subset of monitors?

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, feh

My current setup is 3 monitors, 1920x1080 each, and I use feh to apply a 5760x1080 image across all 3.  What I would like to do is add a fourth monitor (actually a TV) at either 1080x1920 (rotated) or 1920x1080, but I only want to apply the 5760x1080 background to the original 3.  As a bonus, it would be nice to set a separate background on the fourth, but this is not a requirement.  Other than splitting the images apart and applying them that way, is there any way to stretch an image across a subset of my displays?

[xrandr output](https://pastebin.com/dHFQ9MDn)

Comment: I found a solution using feh, but it does not allow me to set a separate background on the TV.  Basically, I set the size of the background image to the combined size of the three main monitors, then offset it the width of the TV so that it fills those three perfectly.  
  
`feh --no-xinerama -g 5760x1080+1080+0 --randomize --bg-center /home/kholby/Pictures/wallpapers/*`